# How to retrieve (Jwt) access token from current user and pass it to a mobile application in asp.net boilerplate (abp)?

Tags: jwt, authorization, bearer-token, abp, asp.net-boilerplate

I am new to asp.net boilerplate ([abp.io](https://abp.io)).

I made a project as backend for an **existing** mobile application.
So I need to retrieve Jwt token from current logged in user and pass it for mobile application which calls Login api.

So please help me how to do that ?
Lots of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

data: `grant_type=password&scope=${oAuthConfig.scope}&username=${username}&password=${password}&client_id=${oAuthConfig.clientId}&client_secret=${oAuthConfig.clientSecret}`,

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code when writing an answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2873538)